# FHIR Value Set Expansion

Tags: asp.net, google-cloud-platform, hl7-fhir, google-healthcare-api

I need to get the example diagnosis codes for a Condition Resource:

http://hl7.org/fhir/ValueSet/condition-code

I have hit the following with Postman:

http://hl7.org/fhir/ValueSet/condition-code/$expand

and this returns a ValueSet but the ValueSet does not include 'expansion' (where the codes would be listed).

How to I retrieve the actual codes for condition-code from hl7?

Comment: I have been able to successfully get the codes using: https://clinicaltables.nlm.nih.gov/valueSetExpand.html but my question still remains because I would like to be able to get other ValueSets (such as body-site for Condition resource without using this api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an actual terminology server for $expand. hl7.org is just a web site, not a terminology server. use tx.fhir.org or run your own terminology server

Comment: thank you! Yes, I can hit https://tx.fhir.org/r4/ValueSet/body-site/$expand?_format=json and receive the codes